# REDIS Bulk RPUSH set values to a list

Tags: redis

Is there an optimized way to RPUSH all the values of a set to a list without SPOP-ing them one by one (or SMEMBERS)? (I need to perform bulk RPUSH of huge set each T time to a list) ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is but not where you'd intuitively think of looking for it. Have a look at [`SORT`](http://redis.io/commands/sort) - this should do what you need:

```
SORT myset BY nosort STORE mylist
```